# ArrayFormula with countif GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am having trouble creating array formula with count if.

What I want to do is display the number of occurrence of a column value.

example :-

```
  A       B  
----     ----
xyz       2 //Arrayformula goes here
xyz       2
abc       1
pqr       3
pqr       3
pqr       3
```

I am using this formula but its not working

```
=ARRAYFROMULA(COUNTA(A2:A,"="&ROW(A2:A)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTIF(A2:A; A2:A))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have column headings, try this in cell `B2`:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",countif(A:A,A2:A),))
```